# What releases of ODL have l2switch working?

Tags: opendaylight

I am new to ODL. I'm using Northbound Networks ZodiacFX switches to learn with.

All the tutorials I read are written on the basis that l2switch is up and working. Without this working I have to manually build all flow table entries to allow basic switch connectivity.

1) What versions of ODL have this feature available

2) Why was proactive l2 switch programming feature removed from ODL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l2switch was removed in Fluorine, so any version before that (Oxygen would be
the most recent) should have l2switch.

It was removed because the project no longer had an active community. It would
be welcome to revive if there were contributors willing to do the work.

Comment: Thank you very much. With l2switch gone, what do people use to get basic switch connectivity? All the basic ARP type switching rules built. Host discovery and all that?

Comment: most likely custom and/or commercial apps. opendaylight can be used in an openstack
environment which helps (with neutron) manage OVS which is openflow based.